# Is there a strict superset of the reals with total order?

Tags: order-theory, ordinals, real-numbers

The ordinals immediately come to mind, but I am mainly interested if there are new elements bounded between two real numbers $[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ that can be added to the reals while preserving total order.

Comment: how do you view the ordinals as a superset of the reals? as for new elements between two reals, are you alluding to adding infinitesimals increments to the reals?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Do the ordinals not include the reals? Then is the union with the reals an answer to my question?

Comment: @Bernard: Is not.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: You're right. It's only maximal for algebraic extensions. I'll withdraw my comment.

Comment: @Bernard: I'm not sure what you mean by that. That it has no ordered algebraic extensions? Sure, that's a property of any real-closed field. That it is the largest algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q$? Not in the slightest.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I meant the first assertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $\Bbb{R\times R}$ with the lexicographic ordering, and identify $\Bbb R$ with the diagonal, namely the points $(r, r)$.

More generally lexicographic products with linear orders and identifying the reals in the product will work pretty much always and will allow you some nice degree of control what sort of new elements you add between real numbers.

The ordinals are not really suitable since they are well ordered, and the reals are pretty far from being well ordered.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can add infinitesimal elements to the reals which satisfy types of the form:

$$\{0<x\}\wedge \{x<a: a \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \} $$

We can do this for every element of $\mathbb{R}$ (we will also have to add a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ to maintain density criterion).  This new structure $\mathbb{H}$, will contain the reals and $\mathbb{R}$ will be a proper subset of $\mathbb{H}$. However, $\mathbb{R}$ will **not** be dense in $\mathbb{H}$. $\mathbb{H}$ will, however, be dense in itself.

Also, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number).